# Response output not showing entire information present in mongoose schema nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have designed a Mongoose schema like this :

```
const metricsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    level : String,
    details: {
         demo: String,
         full: String
    }   
});
```

Also, I have handled the response as such :

```
router.post('/',(req, res, next)=>{
    const metrics = new Metrics({
        _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        level : req.body.level,
        details:{
            demo: req.body.demo,
            full: req.body.full
        } 
    });

    res.status(201).json({
        metrics: metrics
    })
});
```

However, when I use Postman to post JSON data like this :

```
{
    "level" :"schema" ,
    "details":{
        "demo" : "2465",
        "full" : "1211234"
    } 
}
```

I get output like this :

```
{
    "metrics": {
        "_id": "5e09c156b0ce8a4a54a3ecca",
        "level": "schema"
    }
}
```

I do not get the rest of the output : demo and full in the response json. I wish to get the output like this :

```
{
    "metrics": {
        "_id": "5e09c156b0ce8a4a54a3ecca",
        "level": "schema"
        "details": {
            "demo": "2465",
            "full": "1211234"
        } 
    }
}
```

Update: I found one solution in which the Mongoose schema was divided into two parts :

```
const detailsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    demo: String,
    full: String
});

mongoose.model('Details',detailsSchema );

const metricsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    level : String,
    details: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Details'
    } 
});
```

However, this did not work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the code as below:

```
router.post('/',(req, res, next)=>{
    const metrics = new Metrics({
        _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        level : req.body.level,
        details:{
            demo: req.body.details.demo,   <----- see the change here
            full: req.body.details.full
        } 
    });

    res.status(201).json({
        metrics: metrics
    })
});
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Can you please explain this change?

Comment: @Subhadeep Majumder Its just how you read the `req.body` . `demo & full` is inside `details object`. SO we have to read that by one more `dot` notation. Also accept the answer if it solved your problem